# Where to store music?

Tags: ios, app-store

I'm developing an application that downloads music from the web. I now need to upload it to the app store. But I don't know what folder I should save loaded music in. It says that for files downloaded from the Web, I need to use Library/Caches directory, but iOS can remove files from this directory. I don't want that to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store them either in the Documents or the Library directory. (`NSDocumentsDirectory` and `NSLibraryDirectory` constants, respectively.) iOS doesn't remove the files stored in there, as these are not temporary (tmp or Caches) paths.